# How to save item in local storage even after Refresh using js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage, session-storage

I trying to make an editable Resume template. What I want from local storage to whatever the content user adds in my template would stay even after the refresh.

Here is my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Resume Template!</title>
        <style>
            .template
            {
                background-color:#fafdfc;
                height:650px;
                width:550px;
                border:3px solid blue;
                box-shadow:1px 1px 6px;
                padding:10px;
                float:left;
            }
            #temp
            {
                margin:35px 168px;
            }
            @media print{
            body *{
                visibility: hidden;     
                }
            .print-container, .print-container *{
                    visibility: visible;
            }
    }
    </style>
    </head>
   
    <body>

        <div id="temp" class = "print-container" >
            <div class="template" style="float:left; margin-right:15px;">
                <div style="float:left;padding:2px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit0" class = "save">
                    <p id = "edit">
                    <b style="font-size:14px;" id = 'name'></b>
                    <br>
                    <b style="font-size:11px;"></b>
                    <br>
                    <b style="font-size:11px;"></b>
                    <br>
                    <b style="font-size:11px;"></b>
                    <br>
                    <b style="font-size:11px;"></b>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/resume%20pic.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px; margin-left:56px; margin-right:20px; margin-top:8px">
                </div>
                <div style="float:none">
                    <p style="border-top:1px solid black;"></p>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">
                        <b id="edit1" contenteditable="true" style="padding:3px;" class = "save">CAREER OBJECTIVE</b>
                    </p>
                    <p style="font-size:11px;padding:2px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit2" class ="save">To associate myself with a reputed organization where I can utilize my skills to fulfil the goals & objectives of the organization and could enhance my competencies and potential.</p>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">
                        <b contenteditable="true" id="edit3" style="padding:3px;" class = "save">EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION</b>
                    </p>
                    <table style="font-size:11px; border:1px solid black;padding:4px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit4" class = "save">
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Course</b>&emsp;</td>
                            <td><b>Board/University&emsp;</b></td>
                            <td><b>Name Of Institute&emsp;</b></td>
                            <td><b>Year Of Passing&emsp;&emsp;</b></td>
                            <td><b>Percentage/CGPA</b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>B.tech (CSE)</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>CBSE</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>ICSE</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">
                        <b contenteditable="true" id="edit5" style="padding:3px;" class = "save">TECHNICAL SKILLS</b>
                    </p>
                    <ul style="font-size:11px; padding-left:15px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-right:2px;padding-top:2px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit6" class = "save">
                        <li>Beginner of Jquery, Bootstrap, Nodejs, Reactjs, Express, Mongodb.</li>
                        <li>Proficient in C, Python, HTML, CSS.</li>
                        <li>Sufficient Knowledge of C++, SQL, Data Structure, DBMS, Javascript.</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">
                        <b contenteditable="true" id="edit7" style="padding:3px;" class = "save">TRAININGS ATTENDED</b>
                    </p>
                    <ul style="font-size:11px; padding-left:15px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-right:2px;padding-top:2px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit8" class = "save">
                        <li>Attended 40 days training on "C++" at "WEBCOM Technologies, Yamunanagar" (June 2019 to July 2019).</li>
                        <li>Attended 21.5 hours training on "Python" from "Udemy" (July 2020 to Aug 2020).</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">
                        <b contenteditable="true" style="padding:3px;" id="edit9" class = "save">ACADEMIC PROJECTS UNDERTAKEN</b>
                    </p>
                    <ul style="font-size:11px; padding-left:15px">
                        <li contenteditable="true" style="padding:2px;" id="edit10" class = "save">
                            <div style="float:left">
                                <b>TRAVEL MANIA - </b>
                            </div>
                            <div style="font-style:italic; float:right; margin-right:40px">(Duration - 2 months)</div>
                            <div style="float:none">
                                <br>
                                (It is a travelling website that enables users to plan their travel without any hassle. It is a team project in which I worked as a front-end developer.)
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="template">
                <ul style="font-size:11px; padding-left:15px">
                    <li id="edit11" contenteditable="true" style="padding:2px;" class = "save">
                        <div style="float:left">
                            <b>JARVIS - PERSONAL ASSISTANT - </b>
                        </div>
                        <div style="font-style:italic; float:right; margin-right:48px">(Duration - 1 week)</div>
                        <div style="float:none">
                            <br>
                            (This project assists the end-user with day to day activities like searching queries in Google, finding locations, sending emails, playing songs, searching instagram profiles, opening webcam and many more.)
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    </li>
                    <li id="edit12" contenteditable="true" style="padding:2px;" class = "save">
                        <div style="float:left">
                            <b>RESPRO - </b>
                        </div>
                        <div style="font-style:italic; float:right; margin-right:40px">(Duration - 2 months)</div>
                        <div style="float:none">
                            <br>
                            (It is a website that provides a simple and efficient way of creating resume and cover letter for individuals. It is a team project in which I worked as a front-end developer.)
                        </div>
                       
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">
                    <b id="edit13" contenteditable="true" style="padding:3px;" class = "save">SOFT SKILLS</b>
                </p>
                <ul style="font-size:11px; padding-left:15px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-right:2px;padding-top:2px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit14" class = "save">
                    <li>Teamwork</li>
                    <li>Leadership</li>
                    <li>Communication skills</li>
                    <li>Time management</li>
                </ul>
                <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">
                    <b contenteditable="true" id="edit15" style="padding:3px;" class = "save">ACHIEVEMENTS</b>
                </p>
                <ul style="font-size:11px; padding-left:15px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-right:2px;padding-top:2px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit16" class = "save">
                    <li>Won third position in FashP competition (2019).</li>
                    <li>Won first position in Flower Arrangement competition (2012).</li>
                    <li>Won second position in Drawing competition (2012).</li>
                    <li>Won certificate for best entry in group D of All India Camel Color Contest (2011).</li>
                    <li>Participated in Snacks Making competition (2011).</li>
                    <li>Participated in many Dance competitions.</li>
                </ul>
                <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">
                    <b contenteditable="true" id="edit17" style="padding:3px;" class = "save">PERSONAL PROFILE</b>
                </p>
                <p style="font-size:12px;padding:2px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit18" class = "save">
                    <b></b>
                    <br>
                    <b> </b>
                    <br>
                    <b></b>
                    <br>
                    <b> </b>
                    <br>
                    <b>Hobbies - </b>Crafting, modeling, listening to music
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id = "safe">Save</button>
        <input type="button" id = 'print' onclick = "window.print();" value = "print">
        <script src ="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my js:

```
document.getElementById("safe").addEventListener("click", function(){
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".save");
for(var i =0; i<x.length; i++)
{
    x[i].removeAttribute("contenteditable");
}
});

document.getElementById("temp").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".save");
    for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
        x[i].setAttribute('contenteditable', "true");
    }
});

var store = document.getElementById('name');

function populateStorage(){
  
    localStorage.setItem('name',document.getElementById('name').innerHTML)
    var store = localStorage.getItem('name')
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = store;

}

store.onchange = populateStorage;
```

for now, I am trying to save only one item in localStorage i.e `id = name`, and get it back even after the Refresh.

Please help me it's very frustrating.

Comment: One option you have is to create a polling function that periodically inserts the entire DOM content into local storage. You can then, on mount, inject the entire saved HTML from local storage

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the suggestion. actually, I don't know know how to apply it if you please provide resources.

Answer (score 0):

So one thing you are misunderstanding is that localStorage keeps the data even after refreshing the page.

Although you might want to add a check if there is data in the localstorage before adding anything to it.
Right now you are adding anything without looking for anything

```
if(localStorage.getItem('name') == undefined ) {
           // set name data hee
}else {
           // use the pre-existing data.
}
```

Comment: `function populateStorage(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('name') == undefined ) {
        // set name data hee
        localStorage.setItem('name',document.getElementById('name').innerHTML)
}else {
        // use the pre-existing data.
        var store = localStorage.getItem('name')
        document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = store;
}` I tried this but did not work. and also this one https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_localstorage but not worked don't know where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

the `store.onchange` don't trigger, because root parent of `name` element is also editable, so you are changing the `edit0` actually instead of changing `name`. You should listen on `input` event for `id="edit"`.

`edit.addEventListener('input', ()=> { console.log('trigger') })`

when an element has `contentEditable` attribute, you should listen to `input` event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Comment: if you please elaborate it more. i am not able workout only with this information. `var edit = document.getElementById('edit');edit.addEventListener("click", function(){if(localStorage.getItem('name') == undefined ) { // set namedataheelocalStorage.setItem('name',document.getElementById('name').innerHTML)}else {// use the pre-existing data. var store =localStorage.getItem('name')document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = store;}});` I tried this